# What is the delay between a event happens and it is reflected in Admin Reports API, reports.acitivities.list

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Say using Admin Reports API
reports.activities.list
with applicaitonName =  login

Is there any delay between when a user in the domain logins and it is shown up in the response result?

If using push notification, is it realtime?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push  I am trying to use this push notification. I have tested with applicationName = login and applicationName = calendar. It is usually like around 1 hour delay after the event has happened. But I haven't found any official document talking about this delay, so the number 1 hour is not a thing we can rely on.  But could be a good estimation on average delay.

Answer (score 0):

Reports and the Reports API for Apps are always delayed. This delay can be anywhere from a few days to about a week. There's really no way to know.

If you're looking for near real time login details, you're going to need to pull the login time via the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) but this is only web login AFAIK.

Comment: Does it mean even for push notification, the push no is sent when it's available not when the event happens?

Comment: I'm not sure what specific push notification you're referring to but, yes, the data just isn't there for days so I suspect that's when the notification would be too. If you check the Admin console or pull with the API, data will be missing or incomplete until the list has been fully populated by Google.